# Unity FCM Get Data messages in background

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

FCM Unity plugin gives you message received callback only when your app is in foreground because that is when you can register fro callback.

I am developing a plugin which shows notification, is there any way where I can get message data when app is in background to show push notifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we know *Unity engine is a foreground process*, so we can not expect Unity to run scripts while the app is closed.

But **firebase can itself run in the background regardless of app's engine state**.

It will receive the message and save it in the intent of the activity, so when the user opens the app the activity will run and the intent data will be passed to `onMessageReceived`.

According to [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/unity/client), to achieve this, you need to use `com.google.firebase.MessagingUnityPlayerActivity` instead of `UnityPlayerActivity`.

Or if you cannot do this and are extending some other activity neighther firebase's, check [this part](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/unity/client#configuring_a_custom_entry_point_activity) of the docs.